# Create Personal Access Token in Databricks for other users as an Admin

Tags: databricks

How do I create Personal Access Token in Databricks for other users in bulk as an admin activity.

Comment: You can't. API does not allow that. It's like you knew other users' passwords.

Comment: I am stuck here. I have an automated process to do JDBC connection using user's PAT to have proper access control. Do not want user to generate and share the token with admin, and then the admin adds them to the configuration.